# Integrable functions and absolute values

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functions

[image: question]

I have qutoted that the absolute value of an integral is less than or equal to the integral of an absolute value of a function.

I have also said $|-g(x)| \le g(x) \le |g(x)|$ implies the integral g(x) is between the negative and positive absolute value integrals. I believe this implies the integral of g(x)=0?

I am struggling to put together a logical proof, any help would be great.

Comment: I would love to answer but the way the OP, on [this other page](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/763491/6179), apparently silently downvoted the two answers posted and never answered the queries for clarifications, is making me shy.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is based on the fact that, since $g$ is continuous, the existence of a point at which $|g(x_0)|>0$ implies the existence of a little interval $(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$ where $|g|>0$. Therefore $\int_a^b |g| \geq \int_{x_0-\delta}^{x_0+\delta} |g|>0$.

Answer (score 0):

(a) Take a look of [Mean Value Theorem for integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorems_for_integration).

(b) Haow about $f(x)=x$, for $x\in[-1,1]$?

(c) You should try $f(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor$, for $x\in[0,1]$.

Comment: I have set $m=min g(x)=0, M=max g(x)=0$, where $g(x)=0$ I have quoted the theorem saying: $0 = m \le 1/(b-a)\int_a^b |g(x)| dx \le M=0$ so that the integral is equal to zero. However, how do I show this in the other direction?